# Concatenar en jquery laravel

Tags: laravel, script

necesito concatenar pj ...

```
var pj = data.item.attributes.image;  
console.log(pj);           
var imagen = "{{ asset('imagenes/articulos/"  + pj +   "')}}";
```

pero como resultado obtengo

imagenes/articulos/"  +pj+   "

Comment: Que obtienes si haces sólo `var imagen = "{{ asset('imagenes/articulos') }}";`?

Comment: http://localhost/miproyecto/public/imagenes/articulos/&quot;  +pj+   &quot; el detalle es que no logro contatenar la variable " pj " que tiene el nombre de una imagen X

Comment: si hago un log de pj el nombre de la imagen esta ahí ...  pero en la ruta no me lo renderiza ...

Comment: esto es lo que obtengo   http://localhost/miproyecto/public/imagenes/articulos

Comment: Ahora sí. Ya tienes una respuesta con una explicación. Lo que escribas en PHP se ejecutará en el servidor (antes), y lo que escribas en javascript  en el navegador (después). O sea no puedes mezclarlos. Puedes hacerlo como en la respuesta de abajo, o simplemente `var imagen = "{{ asset('imagenes/articulos') }}" + "/" + pj;`

Comment: excelente, patine un buen rato, una mas para la bolsa, gracias :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Php es un lenguaje del lado del servidor por lo que te entregó no puedes modificarlo dinámicamente, para tu código, necesitas preparar el asset y modificarlo despues de recibir el dato `pj`

Utiliza lo siguiente

```
let pj = data.item.attributes.image;  
console.log(pj);           
let imagen_uri = "{{ asset('imagenes/articulos/{pj}') }}";
imagen_uri = imagen_uri.replace('{pj}', pj);
console.log(imagen_url);
```