# Añadir a una ruta variables de AJAX

Tags: laravel, ajax

En una respuesta de un formulario que envio a través de AJAX, en el success tengo un `location.href` y quiero mandar parametros por get, es posible??

Este es mi AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
  headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
  url:"{{ url('calculaAhora') }}",
  data: $(this).serialize(),
  type:"post",
  dataType:'json',
     success:function(respuesta){
        console.log(respuesta);
     },
     location.href = "{{ url('tu-calculo', ['sistema' => "+ respuesta.sistema +", 'clientes' => "+ respuesta.clientes +", 'ticket' => "+ respuesta.ticket +"]) }}" //Aquí es donde quiero mandar lo que recibo por la respuesta del AJAX.
     error:function(jqXHR, textStatus){
     },
})
```

El `console.log(respuesta)` me trae lo siguiente.

```
{sistema: "shr", clientes: "entre16-25", ticket: "entre41-60", email: "correo@gmail.com"}
clientes: "entre16-25"
email: "correot@gmail.com"
sistema: "shr"
ticket: "entre41-60"
__proto__: Object
```

Es posible meterlo, ahora mimo la ruta solo me lee :

`/tu-calculo/%2B%20respuesta.sistema%20%2B/%2B%20respuesta.clientes%20%2B/%2B%20respuesta.ticket%20%2B`

Comment: No se puede mezclar php (que se ejecuta en el servidor) con js (que se ejecuta en el cliente). Puedes probar algo así `location.href = "{{ url('tu-calculo') }}" + "?sistema=" + respuesta.sistema + "&clientes=" + respuesta.clientes + "&ticket=" + respuesta.ticket;` dentro de las llaves de la función `success`.

Comment: Gracias @porloscerrosΨ es verdad así si que funciona pero me pone `/tu-calculo?sistema=objetivo&clientes=entre16-25&ticket=entre41-60` es posible quitar ese simbolo `&` ya que la ruta de laravel es así: `Route::get('/tu-calculo/{sistema}/{clientes}/{ticket}', 'app@tuCalculo');`

Comment: Ah, ok. Entonces podrías hacer algo como lo que se propone en esta [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/351237/92278)

Comment: No lo entiendo muy bien, es como hacer un replace?? puedes ayudarme por favor!?

Comment: Claro, es como hardcodear esos `{sistema} `, `{clientes} `, `{ticket}` en la url que genara php (laravel), y luego reemplazarlos en js con lo que te devuelve la llamada ajax. Son varias líneas para ponerlo en un comentario. Te lo escribo en una respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias @porloscerrosΨ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No se puede mezclar php (que se ejecuta en el servidor) con js (que se ejecuta en el cliente).
Basándome en lo que propone esta [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/351237/92278) lo adapto a tu código:

```
let url = "{{ url('tu-calculo/{sistema}/{clientes}/{ticket}') }}";
url = url.replace('{sistema}', respuesta.sistema);
url = url.replace('{clientes}', respuesta.clientes);
url = url.replace('{ticket}', respuesta.ticket);
location.href = url;
```

En la primer línea, se hardcodean esos `{sistema}`, `{clientes}`, `{ticket}` en la url que genera php (laravel), por lo que la url quedaría mas o menos así:

```
http://midominio.com/tu-calculo/{sistema}/{clientes}/{ticket}
```

y luego vas reemplazando en js con lo que te devuelve la llamada ajax.
Si `respuesta.sistema` tiene como valor `objetivo`, en la segunda línea, la url quedaría:

```
http://midominio.com/tu-calculo/objetivo/{clientes}/{ticket}
```

Y lo mismo con las siguientes.

Comment: Brillante, es una respuesta genial. Además de funcionar he aprendido algo nuevo. Gracias maestro!